# Poiinters in visual C++

Tags: pointers, visual-c++

How do I use pointer in visual studio every time I declare a pointer using

```
int *pointer;
```

I get a build error leave alone other operations with them. Is there something which must be done to use pointers with VC++

Error code C4101

However when I use the pointer in the code I get an error LNK1168

**Edit:** issue solved restarting the IDE along with assigning a value to the pointer solves it. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It just says build error with C4101 being the error code.

Comment: If it is just a build error then it may be, or may not be about the pointer, we need more details to know what is happening with your code. Just saying that it gives you an error is not enough

Comment: @fernando.reyes Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C4101 is not an error, but a warning and you get it because you just declared your pointer without referencing something.

So try to initialize the pointer like this:

```
// Initialize with the null pointer:
int* i = nullptr;

// Or initialize with a valid address:
int ival = 5;
int* ipoint = &ival ;
```

Anyways, you should think of using references or smart pointers instead of raw pointers.